# Furnace starts but Blower doesnt start

Tags: hvac, furnace, blower

I have been having challenges with my furnace starting last winter. Every now and then the furnace doesn't start. When I go down to HVAC and open the panel and force it to restart, I see the filament turn on and fire start, but the blower doesn't start even after 50-60 seconds. At last around one minute later, the furnace stops. Occasionally, it would start working again, but don't know when it would stop. I called maintenance guys and about 4-5 people took a look at it and they said Gas Valve was bad and replaced it, which didn't help. Then they replaced limit switch and flame sensor and circuit board. My furnace is only 4.5 years old and I don't believe any of these parts really had a problem. The last technician who came was honest and at least didn't suggest that any part was broken. Since the problem was intermittent and it was running when this last person came, he still checked and said there could be a problem with blower running at medium speed sometimes.
He has done wiring now in such a way that both AC and furnace operate at high speed. He left it that way to test his theory before actually replacing anything. So my question is, Is it OK to leave both AC and furnace to operate at high speed for blower? What risk am I taking with this? IS his theory correct? IF not, what could be the problem? If that theory can be correct, how do we fix it?

Comment: Most furnaces will have some sort of blinking LED or number display to show an error code.  Have you seen this?

Comment: Most of the risk is in higher electrical costs and probably lower efficiently.  Since this is being done as a short term test(?) it should be okay.

Comment: Cold air is denser and must be pushed harder. And you don't want to be air-cooled by your furnace so that's as slow as possible. - the only things that are left is the rest of the safety chain's pressure switches, the inducer blower, and the start capacitor on the main blower.

Comment: "there could be a problem with blower running at medium speed sometimes" - sure. Any error code is likely to show *over temp limit open* which would be doing its job because it's on fire and not blowing, and that tells you nothing. The inducer (exhaust fan) runs, right?

Comment: One thing I was never sure on is how, when and what calls the blower to come on. I think it's a time delay chip on the board, which they replaced, so...

Comment: What make and model is this furnace?

Comment: I think Mazura is correct, as my blower always starts 20-30 seconds after the furnace is on if the blower is set in the auto position. Why do you want it to start when the heat is not ready yet? Also, the blower only helps to push the hot air to circulate, I don't think high speed is necessary but to cause more wear because of being over-worked.

Comment: I think the main reason for 2 speeds is noise levels and comfort.  Running it at full speed might be a bit nosier and feeling air movement usually makes you feel it's colder than it really is (evaporative effect on your skin).   There really are not any risks with doing this, many furnaces only have one speed, "on full or off"!    Next:  I hate it when techs just throw parts in without properly diagnosing it first. (that's my rant for the day!)